# Applying SonarQube Source File Exclusions

Tags: environment-variables

Using SonarQube 9.6.0,

I have a file `frontend/frontendUI/src/services/mock-data.ts` that contains, as per its name, a lot of quick-and-dirty mock data, which does not really make any sense or confirms to particular styles.

I'd like to skip SonarQube analysis of this file - and indeed, of a few other files also named "mock-*".

To that end, I found [this corresponding section](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/#header-4) of the manual:

> **Project level**
>
> *Project Settings > General Settings > **Analysis Scope > A. File Exclusions***
>
> - **Source File Exclusions**: One or more wildcard patterns defining which files are filtered out from those defined by `sonar.sources`. This can also be set in a configuration file using the key `sonar.exclusions`.

On the screen, where I can do this, this is the displayed wildcard definition:

> You can use the following wildcards. [...]
> *    Match zero or more characters
> **    Match zero or more directories
> ? Match a single character

I went ahead and tried the following variants of entry:

- `**/mock-*` - This one would be ideal.
- `**/mock-data.ts`
- `frontend/frontendUI/src/services/mock-data.ts` - This is copied straight from a report in the file.

Each time I re-ran the analysis after saving it. But none of them work - the previously reported issues remain.

Looking into my Scanner Scope, I see that the entered values have been applied successfully, though.
Here are relevant values (as far as I can tell) of my second try:

```
Project server settings:
- sonar.exclusions=**/mock-data.ts,frontend/frontendUI/src/services/mock-data-backend-service.ts
Project scanner properties:
- sonar.exclusions=**/*pb.go,**/dist/**
- sonar.inclusions=**/*.go,**/*.ts
- sonar.sources=gocode,frontend
```

... Now, I tried instead to use the configuration "Ignore Issues on Multiple Criteria":

- Rule Key Pattern: `*`
- File Path Pattern: `**/mock-*` (the ideal pattern from above)

This time, after rerun all previous reports in that file (and the others starting with "mock-") have vanished as expected!

Although this presents a viable workaround, I would rather use the intended tool.

**How do I correctly use "Source File Exclusions"**?

Comment: Unfortunately I had to select one tag, but did not find any one that seemed to match. If someone with more Rep could please create a "SonarQube" tag? There are several SonarQube-specific questions on this page, so it might be the most fitting. Any other tag correction/suggestion also welcome.